# Why WebAPI does not use my JSONP formatter to deserialize model?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jsonp, deserialization, formatter

I'm very very confuse about Microsoft brand-new framework, ASP.NET MVC WebAPI. I try to create complete solution for cross-site API with JSONP data.

First, I modify their default WebApiConfig to the following code.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});

        // Custom customization
        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonpFormatter());
    }
}
```

I use jQuery to create a request to this API website.

```
// jQuery will create HTTP GET the following URL
// http://localhost:3557/api/FlightAvailability/SearchFlight?callback=jQuery18206342989655677229_1353568617029&origin=JFK&destination=SLC&isOneWayFlight=false&departFlightDate=Wed%2C+28+Nov+2012+17%3A00%3A00+GMT&returnFlightDate=Wed%2C+05+Dec+2012+17%3A00%3A00+GMT&numberOfGuests=1&numberOfChildren=1&numberOfInfants=1&preferredCurrency=USD&query=%7B+Origin%3A+'JFK'+%7D&flightDate=Wed%2C+28+Nov+2012+17%3A00%3A00+GMT&_=1353568618465

$.ajax
({
    url: 'http://localhost:3557/api/FlightAvailability/SearchFlight',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: $.postify(model),
    success: processResponse
});
```

I create action to handle above request. Everything is correct. I can call to this action but WebAPI doesn't use my JSONP formatter to deserialize my query object.

However, I try to directly call ContentNegotiator to get which formatter that handle my request. It's quite surprise that negotiatorResult is my JSONP formatter.

```
[HttpGet]
public List<FlightInfo> SearchFlight(FlightAvailabilityQuery query)
{
    var negotiator = Configuration.Services.GetContentNegotiator();
    var negotiatorResult = negotiator.Negotiate(typeof (FlightAvailabilityQuery), Request, Configuration.Formatters);

    var flight = new FlightsAvailability();

    var result = flight.GetAvailability(WebApiAuthentication.UserInfo.SessionService, query);

    return result;
}
```

Why WebAPI does not use my JSONP formatter to deserialize query FlightAvailabilityQuery object?

[image]

PS. I try to break all possible line in JSONP formatter but Visual Studio doesn't hit any break point by it directly go to action method without call at my only one formatter. However, when I directly call ContentNegotiator, it hit at my break point correctly.

[image]

**Update #1 - Add JSONP formatter source code**

```
public class JsonpFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    private readonly JsonSerializerSettings _serializerSettings;
    private string _jsonpCallbackFunction;

    public JsonpFormatter()
    {
        JsonpParameterName = "callback";
        _serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        _serializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
        _serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());

        MediaTypeMappings.Add(new ExtendedQueryStringMapping(JsonpParameterName, "application/json"));
    }

    public string JsonpParameterName { get; set; }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override MediaTypeFormatter GetPerRequestFormatterInstance(Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
    {
        var formatter = new JsonpFormatter()
        {
            _jsonpCallbackFunction = GetJsonCallbackFunction(request)
        };

        // this doesn't work unfortunately
        //formatter.SerializerSettings = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;

        formatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
        formatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        formatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;

        return formatter;
    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream stream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        // Create a serializer
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(_serializerSettings);

        // Create task reading the content
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
                {
                    return serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader, type);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream stream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_jsonpCallbackFunction))
            return base.WriteToStreamAsync(type, value, stream, content, transportContext);

        StreamWriter writer = null;

        // write the pre-amble
        try
        {
            writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(_jsonpCallbackFunction + "(");
            writer.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                if (writer != null)
                    writer.Dispose();
            }
            catch { }

            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
            tcs.SetException(ex);
            return tcs.Task;
        }

        return base.WriteToStreamAsync(type, value, stream, content, transportContext)
                   .ContinueWith(innerTask =>
                        {
                            if (innerTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                            {
                                writer.Write(")");
                                writer.Flush();
                            }

                        }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously)
                    .ContinueWith(innerTask =>
                        {
                            writer.Dispose();
                            return innerTask;

                        }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously)
                    .Unwrap();
    }

    private string GetJsonCallbackFunction(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if (request.Method != HttpMethod.Get)
            return null;

        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request.RequestUri.Query);
        var queryVal = query[this.JsonpParameterName];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryVal))
            return null;

        return queryVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I might misunderstand about some concept of WebAPI. I spend almost 3 days for working on this problem but I never found any complete solution for JSONP.

Comment: BTW, ContentNegotiator is only used on the response side...but i am surprised as to why you are seeing this behavior given that you just have one formatter which is JsonP formatter and this should have been used for deserializing the request...is it possible for you to share your application code?

Comment: What's the propose of ReadFromStreamAsync method? Rightnow, I try to create some custom HttpParameterBinding class to deserilize model.

Comment: ReadFromStreamAsync is called when reading from a body of a request/response. could you share you source code to kiranchalla@hotmail.com, i could take a look at what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your action does not get hit because it cannot model bind your query parameter. Also `JsonP` is for HTTP GET only, so your formatter will not be selected for deserialization. How do you expect your *FlightAvailabilityQuery* being *deserialized*? I saw a lot of query parameters from your *URL*, do you want that be turned into *FlightAvailabilityQuery*?

The easiest way to get that is to use FromUri.

`public List<FlightInfo> SearchFlight([FromUri]FlightAvailabilityQuery query)`

If for some reason that does not work, you can try to add individual query parameter name on the action, such as *origin, isOneWay, destination.* etc. Then inside your action construct the FlightAvailabilityQuery object. 
Also, if you have a lot of actions that you want to reuse this model binding logic, you can register a custom parameter binding to solve that. Please see [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongmeig1/archive/2012/09/28/how-to-customize-parameter-binding.aspx) for how to register a custom parameter binding to solve this.

Hope this helps!